# Vuex computed properties only work with getters

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

When I put this in my Vue component ...

```
// using store getter

computed: {
  authenticated() {
    return this.$store.getters.authenticated
  }
}
```

... it works. The value for `authenticated` is reactive and the computed property returns `true` when the value in the vuex store is `true`.

This should work ... (and would be the right way according to the docs)

```
// using store state

computed: {
  authenticated() {
    return this.$store.state.authenticated
  }
}
```

... but doesn't. The computed property is always `false`.

It doesn't even work on initial state, so I guess it has nothing to do with the action or mutation. The vuex store holds the correct values in the `state` and the `getters` (Firefox Vue DevTools).

My store looks like this:

```
const state = {
    authenticated: authenticate.isAuthenticated(),
};

const getters = {
    authenticated () {
        return state.authenticated
    }
};

const mutations = {
    isAuthenticated (state, isAuthenticated) {
        state.authenticated = isAuthenticated
    }
};
```

So, it works with store getters but not with store state. Afaik the store state should be reactive as well.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What does it do? "Doesn't work" is vague.

Comment: Getters accept state as a parameter. Your getter should be `authenticated(state) {return state.authenticated}`.

Comment: Do you export the state alongside with the getters,actions and mutators?

Comment: @RoyJ you are right, I updated the question and hope the problem is clearer now.

Comment: @Sletheren yes I do.

Answer (score 3):

More as an aside to this discussion, vuex offers the `mapGetters`, `mapState`, `mapActions`, and `mapMutations` helper functions.

In the case of the `authenticated` getter, you would map it like:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex

computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        authenticated: 'authenticated'
    })
}
```

Helps to keep your code clean and concise, imo.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you construct your Vuex.Store as I do below, the computed works as expected using either `state.authenticated` or `getters.authenticated`.

The mutations section made no difference, so I took it out to make things minimal.

As Bert noted, your getter should take `state` as a parameter; otherwise, it is using the declared `const`, which is the same thing in this case, but deceptive to read.

```js
const authenticate = {
  isAuthenticated() {
    return true;
  }
};

const state = {
    authenticated: authenticate.isAuthenticated()
};

const getters = {
    authenticated (state) {
        return state.authenticated;
    }
};

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    authenticated() {
      return this.$store.state.authenticated;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vuex@latest/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Anything? {{authenticated}}
</div>
```

Comment: The problem in my case is, that the `getter` works but the `state` does not. I don't get why I have to use a getter when the state should work as well. The state is exported as well.

Comment: @RicoLeuthold: Have you solved the issue. I am encountering the same issue. I am not able to get the `state` to work even with `mapState`.

Comment: state should be a well defined source of 'truth'.  Running functions that can change your state at the same time you access your state isn't best practice... and could be the source of your error. `state.authenticate` should simply be true or false.  Changing that value should be handled by an action/mutation.

Answer (score 1):

```
const state = {
   authenticated: authenticate.isAuthenticated(),
};
```

The state is an object. An attribute in the object is trying to call the result of a function. This might be the problem, as it would be asking an object to invoke functions. Try setting it to a fixed value first, and change the state value by invoking a mutation when needed.

You could also try js object function call to invoke the `authenticate.isAuthenticated()` function inside the state object.
Details here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp

Possible solution:

```
const state = {
   authenticated: function(){ return authenticate.isAuthenticated() },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the problem is with using getters or state. Since state ran correctly, getters should do the same since it is pointing to state. Have you exported getters from your store? That seems to be the likely issue. As previously mentioned, you ought to pass state as a parameter when using vuex getters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).