# Vuex action not updating state when calling from component everytime

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to filter my blog posts using vuex. On my route change, I am updating the data from my URL to get the category name, then using it as the action payload. I am doing this in the method and calling the method in 'mounted'. My computed has the getter to get the blogs state. Now the filtering is working sometime and sometime not. No error is showing. Only the getter is getting the state in it's initial state. I am new to VUEX. Here is my code. Want to know what I did wrong here and is there any optimal way to do this:

my store.js:

```
state: {

        blogpost: [],

    },
    getters: {
        getblogPost(state) {
            return state.blogpost
        },

    },
    actions: {
        getblogPost(context) {
            axios.get('/blogpost')
                .then((response) => {
                    // console.log(response.data)
                    context.commit('getblogPost', response.data.posts)
                })
        },
        getPostByCatName(context, payload) {
            axios.get('/categorypost/' + payload)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data.posts)
                    context.commit('getPostByCatName', response.data.posts)
                })
        },

    },
    mutations: {
        getblogPost(state, payload) {
            return state.blogpost = payload
        },
        getPostByCatName(state, payload) {
            state.blogpost = payload
        },

    }
```

Here is the script of my component. All I want is to poplate the allPost() with the filtered blogs everytime, not sometime!

```
data() {
        return {
            categoryName: this.$route.params.catName,
        }
    },

    computed: {
        allposts() {
            return this.$store.getters.getblogPost
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.filterPosts()
        this.$store.dispatch("getblogPost")


    },
    methods: {
        filterPosts() {
            this.$store.dispatch('getPostByCatName',
                this.categoryName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752801/vuex-computed-properties-only-work-with-getters

Comment: Use `mapGetters and mapActions` instead.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use a computed property, instead of a method

```
computed: {
  filteredPosts() {
    return this.$store.getters.getblogPost.map(x => x.category === this.$route.params.catName;
  }
}
```

computed properties are "more reactive" than methods. This way you rely on data reactivity and not to getting the right sequence of the methods